# Sharepoint 2010/2013 Document Library - Access older version of document based on the metadata

Tags: sharepoint-2010, metadata, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary, document-versioning

Can we find a document with older version based on the metadata or can we make the sharepoint search to crawl the docuement's older version when searched by metadata through CAML query or api ?

Answer (score 0):

No, caml only crawls current version